# LINQ: Successfully inserted data to Database but cannot find the value of a specific column

Tags: c#, windows

My code works on inserting data to the database. However, if I try to update it (right after inserting), a column value shows empty string. However, if I restart my application, the value would appear. Here's my code:

```
using(var ctx = LinqExtensions.GetDataContext<MyDataContext>("MyDB"))
{

var memoD = ctx.DataContext.MemoEntities.Where(p=>p.VoucherNo == det.VoucherReferenceNumber).FirstOrDefault();

if(memoD != null)
{

memoD.VoucherNo = String.Empty;

ctx.DataContext.SubmitChanges();

}

}
```

Comment: try to use ctx.DataContext.AcceptChanges() this might work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was solved by adding a datacontext refresh after ctx.DataContext.SubmitChanges()

```
memoD.VoucherNo = String.Empty;
ctx.DataContext.SubmitChanges();
ctx.DataContext.Refresh(RefreshMode.KeepChanges,memoD);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following. Hope to help, my friend.

```
using(var ctx = LinqExtensions.GetDataContext<MyDataContext>("MyDB"))
{

var memoD = ctx.DataContext.MemoEntities.Where(p=>p.VoucherNo == det.VoucherReferenceNumber).FirstOrDefault();

if(memoD != null)
{

memoD.VoucherNo = String.Empty;
ctx.DataContext.MemoEntities.AddOrUpdate(memoD);
ctx.DataContext.SubmitChanges();

}

}
```